# How to serve a react app on express subdomain?

Tags: node.js, express, react-router, subdomain

we have a Single Page React App that we're currently hosting within a public endpoint like awesomewebsite.com/app . It initially did work but the server would redirect to a 404 page if refreshed. We tackled the problem by including a wildcard route under the main router. We now want to carry the whole thing to a sub-domain but applying the same trick there just doesn't seem to make it.

When served under public this one works

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use('/webapp/*',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public/webapp/index.html'))
})
```

But this one doesn't

```
app.use(subdomain('app', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'reactApp'))));
app.use(subdomain('app', express.Router().use('/*',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'reactApp/index.html'))
})));
```

Anyone has any idea as to why this happens and how can we tackle it by using express-subdomain? Thanks in advance, respectfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you merge them, it should work.

```
app.use(subdomain('app', express.Router()
    .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'reactApp')))
    .use('/',function(req,res){
         res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'reactApp/index.html'))
        //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public/webappbeta/index.html'))
    })
));
```